# The hostname for ansible playbook not resolving

Tags: ansible

I want to create a generic playbook so I can pass the values that I want once I call it, but it is failing to resolve the name of the host.

The `inventory.yml` looks like:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
      ansible_host: localhost
    host2:
      ansible_host: localhost
  vars:
    app:
      server: "host1"
      port: 8080
```

The playbook `test.yml` looks like:

```yaml
---
- name: "Printing the hostname"
  vars:
    hostname: "{{ app.server }}"
  hosts: "{{ hostname }}"
  roles:
    - {role: print_name}
```

And the role `roles/print_name/tasks/main.yml` looks like:

```yaml
---
- name: "Printing the hostname"
  shell: "hostname"
```

I get an error when I call it:

```sh
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml teste.yml 
ERROR! The field 'hosts' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable. The error was: 'app' is undefined

The error appears to be in '~/teste/teste.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: "Printing the hostname"
  ^ here
```

What am I doing wrong?
I want to be able to select the host in the variable configuration, now I have `app.server: "host1"` but it may change to `app.server: "host2"`, and I need to have that in the repository.

If I change the `test.yml` variable definition to `hostname: "host1"` it works, but I want to keep the name of the host defined in the variables.

Comment: roles tasks files are not playbooks, you don't put `hosts` or `roles` keywords inside it, just tasks. You should edit the question and explain what you want to do to give some context.

Comment: Thanks @BaptisteMille-Mathias 
It was a copy and paste problem, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

`"{{ hostname }}"` is undefined when your launch your playbook. 2 quick ways to fix this.

1. Pass a `-e|--extra-vars` with the server name you want to target, i.e. `ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml teste.yml -e hostname=host1`
2. Better solution IMO because it uses existing ansible functionnalities: modify your playbook to target a wider specific group (e.g. `hosts: all`) and use the `-l|--limit` option to restrict the hosts targeted during the play to a single host or group, e.g.

   ```
   ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml -l host1 teste.yml
   ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml -l my_sub_group teste.yml
   ```

Comment: The hostname is defined as `hostname: "{{ app.server }}"`, if you look at the error message it is complaining that the `app` is the one undefined, I believe it is not resolving the var name in the hosts.

Comment: `app` is undefined at time of play start because it comes from your inventory and might be dependent on the specific host being targeted, it could very well hold a diffrent value for host1 and host2, even though in this case your defined it for the `all` group. Hence `hostname` is undefined. Hence your play fails.